# select2 placeholder display group text and children

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I would like to know if it's possible, with grouped data as input, to add the group text value in the text display after selection.

Let me explain:

My input data(ajax Api request):

```
    {
      "text": "France",
      "children" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Paris"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Lyon"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "Spain",
      "children" : [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "text": "Barcelona"
        }
      ]
    }
```

With this configuration:

`<select class="js-available-states js-states form-control" style="width: 150px"><option></option></select>`

```
    $('.js-available-projects').select2({
        placeholder: {
            id: '1',
            text: 'Select an option'
          },
        ajax: {
          url: '/city',
          type: "GET",
          dataType: 'json',
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
          }
        },
      });
```

For example, if I select "Paris", the text display as a selection in the select2 box is "Paris". 
Is it possible to customize this text by adding the country name? In my example, it would be "France - Paris".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for [`templateSelection`](https://select2.org/selections#templating) option

```js
let data = [{"text":"France","children":[{"id":1,"text":"Paris"},{"id":2,"text":"Lyon"}]},{"text":"Spain","children":[{"id":3,"text":"Barcelona"}]}]

$('.js-available-states').select2({
  data: data,
  placeholder: 'Select an option',
  templateSelection: function(data) {
    let label = $(data.element).parent('optgroup').attr('label');
    label = label ? label + ' - ' : '';
    return label + data.text;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-available-states js-states form-control" style="width: 150px"></select>
```

**UPDATE:** For remote data

```
$('.js-available-states').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/city',
    dataType: 'json',
    processResults: function(data) {
      data = data.map(i => {
        i.children = i.children.map(j => ({ ...j, group: i.text }))
        return i
      })
      return { results: data };
    }
  },
  placeholder: 'Select an option',
  templateSelection: function(data) {
    let label = data.group ? data.group + ' - ' : '';
    return label + data.text;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The weird part is when I test your solution, the data object passed to the templateSelection does not have the 'optgroup'. It seems different as it's an ajax request. Because if I used a static variable, it works but not using an ajax request.

Comment: The API returns exactly the same result(checked with a console.log in "processResults" before the return)

Comment: @Matt its updated. you can also add the `group` property (`optiongroup` label) to children array on the backend if possible